# Running highlight macro in specific styles

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

Below code is trying to highlight words in MS word file that were in lowercase. However I only need it to run in 3 specific Styles (Heading Level 1, Heading Level 2 and Heading Level 3) . Any help on how to also run this to other two specific styles? Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Dim myDoc As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

Dim myPara As Word.Paragraph
For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs

    If myPara.Style.NameLocal = "Heading Level 1" Then

        TitleParagraph myPara

   End If

Next

End Sub

Public Sub TitleParagraph(ByVal ipPara As Word.Paragraph)

Dim myText As Range
For Each myText In ipPara.Range.Words

    If LCase$(myText.Text) = myText.Text Then

        myText.Words.Item(1).HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise

    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If Instr("headinglevel1, headinglevel2, headinglevel3", VBA.Replace(LCase$(mypara.style.namelocal)," ",vbnullstring)) >0 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a way more efficient approach to the problem:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, h As Long
h = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Text = "<[a-z]@>"
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  For i = 1 To 3
    .Style = "Heading " & i
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = h
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A more readable and maintainable way compared the the instr method I posted in Comments is

```
Option Explicit

' In the declarations section of the module
Public Type State

    ' You can also put other private to module variables here
    Level1              As String 'Not very informative names
    level2              As String
    level3              As String

End Type

Private s               As State


'in an initialisation routine
Public Sub init()

    s.Level1 = myDoc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal
    s.level2 = myDoc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal
    s.level3 = myDoc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3).NameLocal

End Sub

Sub ttest()

    Dim myDoc As Document
    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

    Dim myPara As Word.Range
    For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs
    
        If IsTitleParagraphHeading(myPara.Style.NameLocal) Then
    
            TitleParagraph myPara
    
       End If
    
    Next
    
    
End Sub


Public Function IsTitleParagraphHeading(ByVal ipStyleName As String) As Boolean

    IsTitleParagraphHeading = True
    
    Select Case ipStyleName
    
        Case s.Level1: Exit Function
            
        Case s.level2: Exit Function
            
        Case s.level3: Exit Function
            
    End Select
    
    IsTitleParagraphHeading = True

End Function
```